# How to define a unique alias for a self joining association?

Tags: cakephp, foreign-keys, alias, self-join, cakephp-3.x

I'm a cakephp newbie. I designed a mysql database, with an InnoDB table CompetitionRegions with a foreign key referencing the table itself. A foreign key constraint is in place.

cake bake couldn't generate proper code for this automatically, because the self join table alias is the same as the first alias:

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'CompetitionRegions'

```
SELECT CompetitionRegions.id AS `CompetitionRegions__id`, CompetitionRegions.name AS `CompetitionRegions__name`, CompetitionRegions.parent_competition_region_id AS `CompetitionRegions__parent_competition_region_id` FROM competition_regions CompetitionRegions LEFT JOIN competition_regions CompetitionRegions ON CompetitionRegions.id = (CompetitionRegions.parent_competition_region_id) LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

How do I solve this?

class CompetitionRegionsTable::initialize contains this:

```
$this->belongsTo('CompetitionRegions', [
        'foreignKey' => 'parent_competition_region_id'
    ]);
```

Is there a way how I can specify which alias to use for the self join subquery?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is used as the alias, so you'll have to change that. In order for CakePHP to still use the `CompetitionRegionsTable` class, you'll need to specify it via the `className` option.

```
$this->belongsTo('ParentCompetitionRegions', [
    'className' => 'CompetitionRegions',
    // the foreign key options isn't actually necessary with a matching alias
    'foreignKey' => 'parent_competition_region_id'
]);
```

See also **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Associations > Linking Tables Together](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#associations-linking-tables-together)**

> [...] As you can see, by specifying the `className` key, it is possible to use the same table as different associations for the same table. You can even create self-associated tables to create parent-child relationships [...]

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get it to work with the solution proposed by ndm alone. It gives another other issue (ParentCompetitionRegions association does not exist), that I could not fix possibly because I have none to little experience with CakePHP.

After some more research, all I had to do was renaming the foreign key from parent_competition_region_id to parent_id. Apparently in that case, cake bake gets the idea it is a self-referencing field.